# Jruby: shotgun "No such file or directory"

Tags: jruby, env, shotgun

i try to run shotgun but i get the message:

```
/usr/bin/env: jruby: No such file or directory
```

jruby is installed in ~/jruby-1.7.4 and ~/jruby-1.7.4/bin/ is added to the $PATH.

addtional info: i am new to linux

Comment: if you try get the jruby version do you get the same output?  jruby --version

Answer (score 2):

do 'which jruby'.
if it's not found, make sure jruby can be found from $PATH listing until 'which jruby' detects it.